# #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '039c1a02-ecd3-405a-a745-136df5bbecbb

Tags: mysql

For the life of me I can't find the error in my code:
This is the code

```
INSERT INTO ce000
(guid,number,cedate,debit,credit,notes,currencyguid,currencyval,cesecurity,isposted,isprinted,typeguid,usguid) 
VALUES 
    ('039c1a02-ecd3-405a-a745-136df5bbecbb',
      1331,
     '2019-09-01',
      50000,
      200000,
     'My First Entry', 
     '5a8fe466-d2c7-11e9-b2ad-54ab3a1011d7',
      1,1,1,0,
     '0x0',
     '6d102621-d219-11e9-b2ad-54ab3a1011d7')
```

It throws me this error:

```
#1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '039c1a02-ecd3-405a-a745-136df5bbecbb
```

and here is the structure of the ce000 table:

```
1   guid    char(38)
2   number  int(11)
3   cedate  datetime
4   debit   float
5   credit  float
6   notes   varchar(255)
7   currencyguid    char(38)
8   currencyval float
9   cesecurity  int(11)
10  isposted    int(11)
11  isprinted   int(11)
12  typeguid    char(38)
13  usguid  char(38)
14  created_at  datetime
```

Where is the error I can't find it?

Update:
Show create table ce000:

```
CREATE TABLE `ce000` (
 `guid` char(38) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `cedate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `debit` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `credit` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `notes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `currencyguid` char(38) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `currencyval` float DEFAULT NULL,
 `cesecurity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `isposted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `isprinted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `typeguid` char(38) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `usguid` char(38) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`guid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Another Update:
The table ce000 has the following trigger which should fire only if the INSERT statement is missing the guid value, the table sets it to default 0 and the trigger should catch the 0 value and turn it ti uuid():

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `ce000_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `ce000`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.guid = 0 THEN
    SET new.guid = uuid();
  END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: What is the output of ‘show create table ce000‘?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the VARCHAR(38) just to test? Perhaps it is a problem of character encoding using 8 or 16bit

Comment: Works fine for me(in isolation)..do you have a trigger on this table?

Comment: the length of all char values in the insert strings are in par with the column types

Comment: I do have a trigger actually to manage the guid column as primary key
it sets the new value if not given in the insert statement to uuid()

CREATE TRIGGER `ce000_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `ce000`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.guid = 0 THEN
    SET new.guid = uuid();
  END IF;
END

Comment: Ok I just removed the trigger and tried the INSERT and it worked
What is wrong here the trgger isn't supposed to fire unless the guid column value is 0

Comment: This works fine in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kY3Xi9mK5wAKdgfEaWzWWj/1), hence making your problem non-reproductible.

Comment: The problem is in the trigger it appears

Comment: If you have a trigger on the table, please add its code to your qeuestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my GOD

The problem is in the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `ce000_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `ce000`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF new.guid = 0 THEN
    SET new.guid = uuid();
  END IF;
END$$
```

Since guid type is char(38) when I'm telling it if = 0 (without quotes) it doesn't work

so I only added the '0' text quotes to let mysql understand it as a string not INTEGER

GOD my brain is fried

by the way many thanks to [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)

DBFiddle.com is an amazing website, can't believe I didn't know about it before